# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with array of 100 objects

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory, heap-memory

(Sorry for any format errors, I'm a very novice programmer and this is my first question).  I have a moviearray array with a physical size of 100 and a logical size of 15 (the program is a mock movie store that allows for movies to be added and removed by 'adding'
 or 'buying'.  However, in the following line of code, I have a heap space error:

```
    for (int i=0;i<moviearray.length;i++)
    {
        while(moviearray[i].getTitle() !=null)
        {
            CollTitle.append(moviearray[i].getTitle()+"\n");
        }
    }
```

I am really confused because my array is only 100 at maximum.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: the jvm argument `-Xmx512M` may help.

Comment: post stacktrace. also, why do you use an `array`, rather than, say, any form of `List` that would better suit your need?

Comment: You have an infinite while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are increasing `i` in `for` but inside is a infinite `while` loop. 
In result you are creating infinite number of Strings objects.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for a `while` loop. The value of `moviearray[i].getTitle()` never changes, so it will remain `true` if it was not `null` to begin with, which means the `while` loop will loop forever. Just do a `if(moviearray[i].getTitle() != null)` instead.

Comment: I tried changing the while statement to an if statement, but it returns a nullpointer exception, even though the line of code itself checks to see if the title will be null.

Comment: @StantonProgrammer If `moviearray[i]` is null, then it will throw a NullPointer Exception as you cannot call `.getTitle()` on `null`. I thought at least each entry in `moviearray` would be non-null :). You can of course include an additional check `moviearray[i] != null`, but perhaps make sure there are no `null` objects in your `moviearray` to begin with.

Comment: @Knippers Thank you so much! It worked. You do not know how long I spent trying to figure that out. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The loop you have never evaluate to false.

```
while(moviearray[i].getTitle() !=null)
{
    CollTitle.append(moviearray[i].getTitle()+"\n");
}
```

is like having as you never change the i or the title.

```
    while(true)
    {
        CollTitle.append(moviearray[i].getTitle()+"\n");
    }
```

This cause the the out of memory as you in each iteration put something on the heap.

to solve our problem replace `while` with `if`

```
if(moviearray[i].getTitle() !=null)
{
    CollTitle.append(moviearray[i].getTitle()+"\n");
}
```